# Recessed Floor Receptacle

Tags: receptacle

We have floor receptacles under a rug. The actual plug is recessed about 3/4 inch below the face of the receptacle. The low profile plugs that I have found will not reach down to the recessed receptacle due to interference from the wire coming out of the side of the plug.

Should I:

- Change the receptacle to one that is flush?
- Are there low profile plugs with more "reach"?

Is there such a thing as a "electrical spacer" with a male plug on one end and a female receptacle on the other that is only 3'4 long?

Comment: You shouldn't have things plugged in under a rug anyway...

Comment: Sounds like you're planning on putting an extension cord under the rug. Do a YouTube search for "extension cord fire". I'm sure you'll find _loads_ of examples where extension cords used improperly (smashed behind furniture, buried under rugs, mostly wound on a cable spool, etc.) have combusted because flowing electricity generates heat and extension cords are designed to dissipate that heat to air. Trapping that heat causes fire. Also, extension cords under rugs are tripping hazards and just look funny.

Comment: In-floor receptacles of that type are designed for use with standard plugs.

Answer (score 5):

Electrical cords under rugs is a bad idea.

When putting in new underfloor receptacles in an area NOT under a rug, "Stage Floor Boxes" are a better way to handle having a receptacle with minimal impact while in use. The cover opens for access and has slots to let the cords out with the cover closed, rather than having plugs sticking up above floor level. But don't put one under a rug with things plugged into it.

[image: Stage floor box]

*[Image source](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0013%2F1314%2F4934%2Fproducts%2F57_44144720-8bea-41b2-b4af-ffd23b8a9dc1_530x%402x.jpg%3Fv%3D1532076677&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=f5ccc7e94982daf32b2da893c7eee72bbf7ce56ea2f4317824e5be24b2b071b5&ipo=images) no endorsement*